# Two for loops in MATLAB, one not working

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have some code which is running regressions,

I got some great code on stack overflow, yesterday, which helps to insert the x variables.

```
  %My attempt a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
clear; 
% K: horizon
Myarbitrarycombinations= [7 8; 7 4;];

for ii=size(Myarbitrarycombinations,1)
 for j = [1, 2, 3];
     K=j;

Myarbitrarycombinations(ii,1)
Myarbitrarycombinations(ii,2)



end 
end
```

The problem I am having is with the "K" for loop, in the above code.

The code is returning

```
K=1, 7 4
K=2, 7 4
K=3, 7 4
```

However, I would like it to return,

```
K=1, 7 4
K=2, 7 4
K=3, 7 4
```

and

```
K=1, 7 8
K=2, 7 8
K=3, 7 8
```

Comment: What is your error? `K=j; `in line 5 sounds fishy, you don't have j defined there...

Comment: Ok, sorry guys!

Comment: Ok DATA1, is another file, that is helping the regression to run, the x data in xinit

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo, is this what you mean by the minimal, complete and verifiable example. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks @ChrisLuengo, I have always done this wrong, if I ever ask again I will make sure is minimal, complete and verifiable example! Sorry to all that I have made this mistake before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this `for` loop:

```
for ii=size(Myarbitrarycombinations,1)
```

`size(...,1)` is a scalar (2). This is the same as

```
for ii=2
```

meaning that it iterates only once. Instead, do:

```
for ii=1:size(Myarbitrarycombinations,1)
%      ^^^
```